# Clear a cell in Excel after contents used in formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a scenario where if I am to enter a number into a cell, I want that number to be used in another cells formula and than the cell I entered the number in to be cleared after hitting enter.

Example:
Cell G2 has formula `=Sum(A2,B2)-C2`

Cell B2 is 10

Cell C2 is 2

Enter 7 into cell A2

After hitting enter Cell G2 should show 15 and Cell A2 should be cleared.

So far I am only able to get the cell to clear:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am trying to use `Application.Evaluate("Sum(A2, B2) - C2")` for the formula but I cannot get them to work together.

Is this possible?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: G2 either has a formula, or it doesn't. If it has a formula, you may not clear A2. If it doesn't have a formula, you need to calculate that formula entirely in your code and not depend on the sheet having it.

Comment: I think it's possible if it's OK with you to have a "helper cell" as the reference for the formula. For example, the formula is `=sum(A1,Z1)`.  Before `Target.ClearContents`, you copy the target value to Z1 : `range("Z1").value = target.value`. So, although the target value is cleared, but the formula can still have the reference value from cell Z1. Not tested.

Comment: Also be mindful of `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` or `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Evaluate a Formula

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const FormulaColumn As String = "G"
    
    Dim irg As Range
    With Me.Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Set irg = Intersect(.Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), Target)
    End With
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With irg
        Intersect(.EntireRow, Me.Columns(FormulaColumn)).Value _
            = Me.Evaluate(.Cells(1).Address & "+" & .Cells(1) _
            .Offset(, 1).Address & "-" & .Cells(1).Offset(, 2).Address)
        .ClearContents
    End With
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```